# bulk enabling ssh on multiple macs in network

Tags: ssh, mac

Is there a more automated way to enable ssh functionality on all the macs in a network.

At the moment our solution is to manually do this machine by machine... this isn't ideal.

This is part of the set up of Forescouts' CounterACT software.

Comment: Do you have a device running OS X Server on the network?

Comment: No we don't, only windows/linux.